# How to make a Rails 3.2, treeview for contracts records from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, treeview, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a gem or a function for a treeview in rails to show different database tables?
I have the tables. Contracten, contractsoorten, contractopmerkingen. (dutch)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a JavaScript UI framework to handle it for you... Check out Kendo UI... I believe it has a treeview built-in.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try that :)

Comment: i can't find a treeview there. other suggestions?